# Axon Event only picked up by one instance of my service instead of all (fan-out)

Tags: spring-boot, event-handling, axon

We have a Spring micro-service connected to Axon with an @Component and an @EventHandler function on this class. Like this:

```
@Component
@AllowReplay(false)
class AClass {
   
    @EventHandler
    fun on(someEvent: SomeEvent) {
    ...some handling here
    }
}
```

The Event gets picked up normally and everything works fine but when we run multiple instances of our service only one instance of the service picks up the event. I userstand that this has to do with the way the event processors work (https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors) but I need all instances of the service to pick up the event. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much depends on how you are configuring and using it.

So, 'pick up' events, the way you describe, I assume that are events being handled.
In that case, and another assumption here that you are using some sort of Tracking Event Processor (TEP), this is where this logic and responsability is.

In essence, a TEP is responsible for 'tracking' which events it already received to not double react on those.
In your scenario, seems like your apps/instances are sharing the same database (hence sharing the same tokens) and that's why you see it.

About your 'workaround', you are just assigning names to a Processing Group (which can also be done using annotations like this: `@ProcessingGroup("processing-group-name-you-want")`. If you do not assign a name, the package is the default name used.
Every Processing Groups has a tracking token behind it. In this case, you get multiple tokens and 'react' to the same event multiple times.

For more info about Processing Groups, I recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65611474/4437909).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't use the annotation version since I assumed all the instances of my service would end up in the same processing group and dynamic values in annotations do not work so nothing would change. By using the configurer.assignProcessingGroup function I can give a 'random' name to the processing group and thus forcing the events to be picked up by each instance of my service.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that works for me, although not the prettiest: Axon 'merges' processors based on package name so multiple instances of a service result in a single processor.

By using unique processing groups you can trick Axon into not 'merging' the different processors into one.

```
@Autowired
    fun configure(configurer: EventProcessingConfigurer) {
        configurer.assignProcessingGroup { t: String? -> "${t}_${UUID.randomUUID()}" }
    }
```